# I changed website softwares and need to find an alternative to using a query string in the url for Google Analytics Sitesearch

Tags: google-analytics

A site I am currently working on utilizes a q parameter in the query string to send info to their SiteSearch analytics queue. I need to remove the q because it interferes with the way the new site software structure is. I did this:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', urlpath);
```

where urlpath is the path to the page with the Q on it. I figured this would keep things the same without needing to make a change to GA while also finding a workaround on the website. The problem is that every pageview seems to go in there twice now. I assume this is because of the way the above works.

My question is, is this the best way to handle this, if not what is an alternative?

I found this solution here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en#Post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Tag Manager. Is the best solution for this case.
First check and create Form Listener as Trigger (HTML or Ajax or similar for your form).
Second create the Variable, custom query parameter, in this case is the Value typed on form input
Third, duplicate GA tag, PageView and FieldToSet choose Page (aka VirtualPage), and as value the Variable created.

All together when the Trigger fire the tag, generate the pageview dynamically with ?and query. Thus, on your GA view, get this query parameter and remove value and results on your Beh.Report (so for avoid increase pageview with query string).

And DONE!
On your GA Sitesearch Report, you'll see the results without problem!

If you dominate Tag Manager, it works fine, and it's same for Gtag, new global tracking code, but script and coding is directly server-side.